# send USSD with AT Commands in Java

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to make a program to send ussd code to the modem pool and i hope there is a response from the modem. I use AT Commands to send ussd code, I tried to text, but I can, but not for ussd, I've looked for it but to no avail..

I've been looking for it, but not many use java and it's difficult to understand, can you help me with my problem, sorry my language is not good in English

```
// library
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortDataListener;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortEvent;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Gsm {
    private SerialPort serialPort;
    private Logger logger;
    private String result;

    public boolean initialize(String port) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("SP1");
        logger.info("Application start");
        serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPort(port);

        if (serialPort.openPort()) {
            logger.info("Port \"" + serialPort.getSystemPortName() + "\" was opened");
            serialPort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
                @Override
                public int getListeningEvents() {
                    return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
                }
                @Override
                public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                    logger.info("receiving data");
                    byte[] msg = new byte[serialPort.bytesAvailable()];
                    serialPort.readBytes(msg, msg.length);
                    String res = new String(msg);
                    result = res;
                }
            });
            return true;
        } else {
            logger.warning("Failed to open port \"" + serialPort.getSystemPortName() + "\", application stopped.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute USSD command
     *
     * @param ussd : the USSD command
     * @return String contains the response
     */
    public String executeUSSD(String ussd) {
        String cmd = "AT+CUSD=1,\"" + ussd + "\",15\r\n";
        result = "";
        serialPort.writeBytes((cmd).getBytes(), cmd.getBytes().length);
        while (result.equals("")) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (result.contains("ERROR")) {
            return result;
        }
        while (result.contains("OK")) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String str = "";
        if (result.contains("CUSD")) {
            str = result.substring(12, result.length() - 6);
            //String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G....)");
            Iterable<String> arr = Splitter.fixedLength(4).split(str);
            str = "";
            for (String s : arr) {
                int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
                str += (char) hexVal;
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}



import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.NRSerialPort;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;

import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Main {

    static Enumeration portList;
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static SerialPort serialPort;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Check Available ports
        String port = "";
        for(String s:NRSerialPort.getAvailableSerialPorts()){
            System.out.println("Availible port: "+s);
            port=s;
        }
        int baudRate = 115200;
        NRSerialPort serial = new NRSerialPort(port, baudRate);
        System.out.println("Serial Connect : " + serial.connect());
        System.out.println("Serial is Connected : " + serial.isConnected());
        System.out.println("=============================================");

        // send USSD
        Gsm gsmUSSD = new Gsm();
        System.out.println(gsmUSSD.initialize("COM14"));
        System.out.println(gsmUSSD.executeUSSD("*363#"));
        // send SMS
        //USBModem gsmSMS = new USBModem("COM14", 115200);
        //gsmSMS.sendSMS("+xxxxxx", "");

    }
}
```